# How to stop "## NULL" above table in knitr output?

Tags: r, knitr

I just found and started using the `condformat` package in R.

It works great, but when I run the below code, a `## NULL` line shows up just above the table. If I add `include=FALSE`, it drops the `## NULL`, but also the table.

Is there any way to suppress the `## NULL` without suppressing the table?

````
---
title: "condformat_test"
author: "John"
date: "Dec 24, 2016"
output:
  pdf_document
---


```{r setup_chunk, include=FALSE}
library(condformat)
library(knitr)

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE) 

```

```{r condformat_test}

condformat(iris[c(1:5,70:75, 120:125),]) +
  rule_fill_gradient2(Petal.Length)
```
````

Comment: maybe `results = "hide"` or `invisible(_statement_that_prints_null_)`

Comment: @Gregor - sorry about that, forgot to paste it in earlier.

Comment: @MichaelChirico - Thanks, but I just tried those, and both result in the table being hidden as well.

Comment: I think this should be [filed as a bug to `condformat`](https://github.com/zeehio/condformat). From what I can tell the only difference between having `output: html_document` (which doesn't print the `##NULL`) and `output: pdf_document` is that `condformat:::knit_print.condformat_tbl` calls `condformat2html` instead of `condformat2latex`. I suspect the former of these is hiding the `NULL` output properly... I can't see a way around this without editing pretty far into the package code.

Comment: @MichaelChirico - Thank you for all the investigation into the code. I really appreciate it. I'll file a bug report with them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. There was a bug with condformat 0.4.0 that will be fixed in the next CRAN release.

For now, feel free to use:

```
devtools::install_github("zeehio/condformat")
```